# How to change ComboBox selection after selected item is deleted?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, selection

I need to manually change ComboBox selected item to the first one when the selected one is deleted. ComboBox will always have at least 1 item in ItemsSource.

I have tried setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true which solves the issue but creates another one, I have multiple ComboBoxes binded to the same ItemsSource and it modifies selection on all of them.

my ComboBox looks like this

```
// SelectedIndex 0 is to initially select the first item
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
public Item SelectedItem
{
    get => _selectedItem;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_selectedItem, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        _selectedItem = value ?? Items.First();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
    }
}

private Item _selectedItem;
```

The rest of XAML code is dependent on value of SelectedItem and it changes accordingly based on its value, although the visual selection of ComboBox remains empty when the selected item is deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I was able to fix it with this ugly solution

```
public partial class ComboBoxWithDefaultSelection : ComboBox
{
    public int DefaultSelectedIndex { get; set; }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            SelectedIndex = DefaultSelectedIndex;
        }

        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"), just after the deletion code. The problem in your case is the property is not notified on delete. Hence code it accordingly, that after delete operation, invoke the property to update the combo box selected item

Comment: It is deleted from the collection itself from different place than view. Actually one method adds new relevant items, remove outdated items and just then call reset on observable collection so the ComboBox is notified. And it works except for this specific scenario. ComboBox selection options reflect the actual state of the collection but when the selected item gets deleted from the collection then selected item is set to null.

I was able to bypass it with with this line `_selectedItem = value ?? Items.First();` but ComboBox does not update its selection visually.

Comment: Hi, I don't think your solution is ugly, may be that is the right way of doing this.